# Implementing XA transaction for Mule 4 SDK connector

Tags: mule, xa, mule-sdk

I try to implement XA transaction for Mule 4.3.0 custom connector.
In Mule 3.X.X versions and up Mule 4.2.X versions they are supporting  the class

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.transaction.ExternalXaTransaction
```

In 4.3.0 they are removing the above mentioned ExternalXaTransaction class.

How to implement XA transaction in Mule 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a class from an `internal` package ever (example: `org.mule.runtime.core.internal...`). They are implementation classes not meant to be used by user code and are not guaranteed to remain stable between versions.

In a connector created with Mule 4 SDK you should follow the [documented instructions for implementing transactions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/transactions). [XA transactions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/transactions#xa-transactions) require to use the `XATransactionalConnection` instead of `TransactionalConnection`.